# StackOverflowError ao chamar uma classe

Tags: java, android

```java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

Conexao c = new Conexao();

public void tela(){

  c.CriaBanco();


  }
}

public class Conexao extends MainActivity{
  String NomeBanco = "Cadastro";
  SQLiteDatabase BancoDados = null;

  public void CriaBanco(){
        try{
            BancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase(NomeBanco, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
            String SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST tabCadastro ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nome TEXT, telefone TEXT) ";
            BancoDados.execSQL(SQL);
            MensagemAlerta("Banco de Dados", "Banco Criado com Sucesso");
        }catch(Exception erro){
            MensagemAlerta("Erro Banco de Dados", "Não foi possivel criar o Banco" + erro);
        }
        finally {
            BancoDados.close();
        }
    }
    public void MensagemAlerta(String TituloAlerta, String MensagemAlerta){
    AlertDialog.Builder Mensagem = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    Mensagem.setTitle(TituloAlerta);
    Mensagem.setMessage(MensagemAlerta);
    Mensagem.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
    Mensagem.show();

}



}
```

Ao chamar uma classe no android dá esse erro:

```
07-02 18:50:18.090 21687-21687/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-02 18:50:18.090 21687-21687/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-02 18:50:18.160 21687-21695/? E/cutils-trace﹕ Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-02 18:50:18.800 21703-21703/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-02 18:50:18.800 21703-21703/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-02 18:50:21.450 21713-21713/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.gabrielbonatto.oficial
07-02 18:50:22.070 21713-21713/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.gabrielbonatto.oficial, PID: 21713
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Comment: Poste mais do seu código, só com isso não dá para saber ao certo o que é. Mas seja lá o que for, dá um `StackOverflowError` que é o que ocorre quando você tem uma recursão infinita ou muito profunda. Em especial, qual foi a classe do Android que você chamou? Chamou como? O que é a classe `Conexao` e o método `CriaBanco()`?

Comment: editei o código

Comment: O que é a classe `BancoDados`, o método `execSQL(String)` e a classe `MensagemAlerta`? O que é `NomeBanco`?

Comment: @GabrielSantanaBonatto seria interessante renomear os atributos e métodos com a primeira letra minúscula para facilitar a leitura do código.

Comment: Resolver StackOverflow é com a gente mesmo :P

Comment: Quando vi a pergunta pela primeira vez achei que era um erro no site...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sua clase `conexão` extende `MainActivity`. Quando uma nova instância da classe `Conexão` é criada, ela possui um membro `Conexão`, herdado de `MainActivity`. Esse membro, quando criado, irá conter um outro membro `Conexão`, assim por diante.

Você acaba criando infinitas instâncias de Conexão, uma dentro da outra. **Infinitas**? Não, porque a pilha estoura antes, e é esse o erro que você recebe.

Answer (score -1):

Como na sua MainActivity você ***"extends"*** da *ActionBarActivty* você precisa implementar o método *onCreate*

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         // Seu código aqui que chama o Conexao
    }
```

Feito isso na sua Classe Conexao, você pode remover e extends MainActvity e deixar da seguinte forma:

```
    public class Conexao {
        public void criaBanco(){
        // Seu código de criação do banco
        }
    }
```